# '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter development. I'm trying to POST data into a JSON format, its a simple registration page

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Encode body to string, see [Send data](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data#2-sending-data-to-server)

```
final response = http.post(
  Uri.parse('...'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      ...
  }),
);
```